# Google Sign-in for Android app on multiple server environments?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

We've got multiple server environments (e.g. development, staging, release), each as their own project in Google Developer Console, and want to be able to sign in to any of these from our Android app, for testing purposes.

I got Google sign-in for one of the environments working (following the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth)) but when I try to enable the others [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android), I get the following error:

`The SHA-1 you specified is already used with the same package name for a different Android OAuth2 client.`

It seems like we're not allowed to enable Google sign-in for the same packagename/signing certificate hash with multiple projects. So how can I enable Google sign-in for our app for each of our server environments? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems not possible as stated; as the error message says, you can only enable Google sign-in for one backend project per signing certificate hash/packagename combination. What I ended up doing is creating multiple `applicationIds` (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) for different `productFlavors` (one for each endpoint).

Comment: This means that you have multiple applications in the play store. I have only one app, and i need to login to 3 different Firebase projects, but i can't because Google only allows one to have the Fingerprint. How am i suppposed to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Within one dev console project, you can add multiple OAuth 2.0 clients, e.g.

1. multiple instances of your web server (if you don't want to share client id and secret)
2. multiple Android client (each Android client is uniquely identified by package name + signing cert SHA1 hash. And this is something global. package name + signing cert is not secret to other people. You won't want others to fake your Android client and gets the same OAuth tokens. So Google won't allow a 2nd entry in another dev console project)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to resolve this..

You can use a different cert to sign the apps for different environment and also create a different project for each of the environment.

Other option is to use a different package name for each of the environment e.g. com.mycompany.myapp.dev com.mycompany.myapp.staging and com.mycompany.myapp (for production)

You can only have one client id with the same combination of package name and cert hash.