# Need to regenerate my google-service.json

Tags: android, google-signin, google-play-services

I'm totally desperate. I need to regenerate my google-services.json from this web, because I've lost the original json file.

Generate config file

When I put all the data, my project name, package name and my SHA1, it gives me this message
The SHA-1 you specified is already used with the same package name for a different Android OAuth2 client.

I don't know how to solve this, because I know that the key is in that project.

I need the google-services.json in order to get the token from my google sing in.

Any help?

Comment: Try the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806476/google-sign-in-for-android-app-on-multiple-server-environments

Comment: Login to the same account which you created the api key to get the google-services.json file

Answer (score 0):

You should login into google api console to check the oauth credntial with same key value pair and then try doing the steps yoi are doing that should work. In case you have google api console project you can import it in [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/google-android)

Comment: please consider using the comment section for providing information on the question if you're going to properly answer it